# ConcurrentModificationException when processing HashMap

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to put a HashMap`<Object, List<Object>>` into my dataModel, but when i call the template.process() method, I get the following exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
    at freemarker.template.SimpleCollection$SimpleTemplateModelIterator.next(SimpleCollection.java:142)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:157)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:351)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:95)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:172)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:351)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:95)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:176)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:232)
```

After looking over some articles and older questions, I've tried to use a ConcurrentHashMap instead, to the same result. I've also tried making a copy using `new HashMap<Object, List<Object>>(oldHashMap)`. Are there any other common fixes to this problem I could try?

EDIT: I know the general cause of ConcurrentModificationExceptions. Please only reply if you can help me understand why the framework Freemarker is throwing these exceptions, mkay? =)

Thanks!

Comment: Something is modifying the map as it's being looped over. This is not permitted.

Comment: Yes, I've figured as much. Consider this a Freemarker question, not a general Java question even though I labeled it as such.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap doesn't throw a ConcurrentModifcationException. ;)

Comment: Yeah, read about that. Seems that something within Freemarker is making a new HashMap or something. Holding out for a Freemarker-specific answer.

Comment: Show us the template code where the problem is happening.  I'm sure that in a list statement your calling a method to update the map or something like that.

Comment: I've found a workaround, but the map solution would be much easier to manage. Here's the code looping over the map. <#list crossMap?keys as key>
 <td>${(crossMap[key])!"No known uses"}</td>
 </#list>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Synchronise access to the hashmap so that only one thread can be accessing the hashmap at once.

Comment: I'm not certain this would've worked, but it's the only solution so far that might've, since I don't have access to the Freemarker code.

Answer (score 3):

The   `ConcurrentModificationException` is caused by using an invalid iterator after the underlying collection has been changed. The only way to fix this is not changing the collection you are iterating over. In most cases this is not caused by multi-threading.

Simple Example:

```
//throws an exception in the second iteration
for(String s: list){
   list.remove(s);//changes the collection
}
```

fix 1, not supported by all iterators:

```
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    iter.next();
    iter.remove();//iterator still valid
}
```

fix 2:

```
List<String> toRemove = ...;
for(String s: list){
   toRemove.add(s);
}
list.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Comment: I'm not using any of these methods, so this is quite irrelevant. What I need to know is why Freemarker is throwing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that, while you're iterating over the map, something has changed the map's contents.

Your best course of action is figure out what that "something" is. For example, it could be another thread, or it could be that you have a `foreach` loop and modify the map from within the loop.

It is very hard to give advice on how to best fix the problem until we understand what exactly is causing it and what the desired behaviour is.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this kind of problem on `List` and `Map` when doing something like this:

```
List<A> list = ...; //a list with few elements
for(A anObject : list){
  list.add(anotherObject); //modify list inside the loop
}
```

The same goes with maps. The solution is to look for possible places where you might be modifying the map inside the loop over that map. Or if you are using a multi-threaded application, then it's possible that another thread is looping over the map while you are modifying it (or visa-versa). In such case you'll need to synchronize access to the map in both places: looping code and map modifying code.

There some info on it in the Java API for `TreeMap` [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

> The iterators returned by the iterator
>   method of the collections returned by
>   all of this class's "collection view
>   methods" are fail-fast: if the map is
>   structurally modified at any time
>   after the iterator is created, in any
>   way except through the iterator's own
>   remove method, the iterator will throw
>   a ConcurrentModificationException.
>   Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails
>   quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic
>   behavior at an undetermined time in
>   the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an
>   iterator cannot be guaranteed as it
>   is, generally speaking, impossible to
>   make any hard guarantees in the
>   presence of unsynchronized concurrent
>   modification. Fail-fast iterators
>   throw ConcurrentModificationException
>   on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it
>   would be wrong to write a program that
>   depended on this exception for its
>   correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to
>   detect bugs.

Comment: I see, sorry can't help you with freemaker.